# Unable to open pdf file using evince. error while loading libraries: libexpat.so.1

Tags: 16.04, pdf, shared-library, evince

I am unable to open pdf file using evince on Ubuntu 16.04. I get the following error:

> evince: error while loading shared libraries: libexpat.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object

I have the above said library in my system and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is also directed to it via symbolic link. I also tried re-installing the newest version of expat, but in vain. Could anyone help me out here?

As mentioned in a comment, here is the output of `dpkg -S libexpat.so.1`:

```
libexpat1:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
libexpat1:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
libexpat1:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
libexpat1:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
```

and following is the output of `ldd $(which evince)`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffef43a7000)
libevdocument3.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdocument3.so.4 (0x00007ff373db9000)
libevview3.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevview3.so.3 (0x00007ff373b63000)
libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007ff373234000)
libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007ff372f59000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff372d0d000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff372ae8000)
libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007ff3728df000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007ff3725cb000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff3723a9000)
libsecret-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsecret-1.so.0 (0x00007ff37215a000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff371dd2000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff371b7f000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff37186e000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff371565000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff371348000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff370f7e000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff370d7a000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff370b60000)
libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff3708da000)
libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff3705b0000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff3703a3000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ff370069000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007ff36fe59000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007ff36fc53000)
libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff36fa24000)
libepoxy.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007ff36f72f000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff36f519000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007ff36f2d6000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007ff36f0d3000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007ff36eec8000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007ff36ecbe000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007ff36eabb000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007ff36e8b8000)
libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007ff36e679000)
libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007ff36e471000)
libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007ff36e26f000)
libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007ff36e060000)
libmirclient.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9 (0x00007ff36ddb9000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007ff36dba7000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff36d99f000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007ff36d796000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007ff36d4ee000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007ff36d244000)
libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007ff36d01f000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007ff36ce1b000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007ff36cc11000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ff36c9ef000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007ff36c7e5000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007ff36c504000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007ff36c2e2000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ff36c0c7000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007ff36bebf000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007ff36bc4f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff374259000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff36ba4b000)
libgstbase-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff36b7e7000)
liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007ff36b567000)
libatspi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007ff36b338000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007ff36b0ec000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007ff36ae8e000)
libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007ff374411000)
libmircommon.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.7 (0x00007ff36ac47000)
libmirprotobuf.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3 (0x00007ff36a9d5000)
libcapnp-0.5.3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcapnp-0.5.3.so (0x00007ff36a74d000)
libmircore.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircore.so.1 (0x00007ff36a544000)
libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0x00007ff36a340000)
libprotobuf-lite.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9 (0x00007ff36a10f000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff369d83000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff369b6b000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007ff369963000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ff36975f000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007ff369559000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007ff369345000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007ff374387000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007ff36911f000)
libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 (0x00007ff368f07000)
libkj-0.5.3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkj-0.5.3.so (0x00007ff368cde000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007ff368abc000)
```

Comment: Does it say: `Operation not permitted` right after this error message?

Comment: On a different note, you might give Okular or Zathura a try :)

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -S libexpat.so.1` and  `ldd $(which evince)` to the question.

Comment: No @Jos it does not say anything after that error message.

Comment: Hey @N0rbert I have added the required output in the question.

Comment: @SKR I reformatted your post a bit. Hint: to format a ***block*** of code, indent it by 4 characters (or select it and hit CTRL-K). To format ***inline*** code, use the backticks (or select the words and hit CTRL+K).

Comment: Thanks @PerlDuck. New to SE. Will take a while to get used to.

Comment: @SKR Well, then "Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!" No worries, it took me a while, too. I'm glad you formatted it at all :-) For blocks, the indenting just looks prettier, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for `evince` to load the shared library `libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0`.

Actually I had this library at `/usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0`. But when I check the output via running

```
dpkg -S libboost_system.so.1.58.0
```

is

```
libboost-system1.58.0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
```

And found there is not this library at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. So just copy the shared library to the target dir, via

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Then the problem was solved.

Comment: Why not by using `ln -s`?

Comment: Yes. It may also work.

Comment: I have similar error with `libz.so.1` and which exist in many locations in my system, `ldd ...` outputs path to this lib in `~/Downloads/VMWare-vix-...x86_64/vm.../lib64/libz.so.1`

how could I fix this? 

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `libexpat.so.1` library should be located in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1` (as you can see in the output of `dpkg -S libexpat.so.1` and on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=x86_64-linux-gnu%2Flibexpat.so.1&searchon=contents)).

Try to remove the `libexpat.so.1` from */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1* with

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
```

and then reinstall its package for sure with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libexpat1:amd64
```

and finally check Evince with problematic PDF document.

---

**Note:** Usually many files and directories are installed from deb-packages with the help APT (and its utilities - `dpkg`, `apt`/`apt-get`) but in this particular case the */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1* is out of their control, so we need to remove it manually.